# Find Complex Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> > Question:
> >
> > Find the complex roots of $$ {(z^{12} -1)\over (z^4-1)(z^3-1)}  = 0  $$

What I have attempted:

$$ {(z^{12} -1)\over (z^4-1)(z^3-1)} = 0  $$

$$ {(z^{6} -1)(z^{6} +1)\over (z^2-1)(z^2+1)(z^3-1)} = 0  $$

$$ {(z^{3} -1)(z^3 +1)(z^6+1)\over (z+1)(z-1)(z^2+1)(z^3-1)} = 0  $$

$$ {(z^3 +1)(z^6+1)\over (z+1)(z-1)(z^2+1)} = 0  $$

$$ {(z+1)(z^2-z+1)(z^6+1)\over (z+1)(z-1)(z^2+1)} = 0 $$

$$ {(z^2-z+1)(z^6+1)\over (z-1)(z^2+1)} = 0 $$

How should I continue?

Comment: $\frac{z^6 + 1}{z^2+1} = z^4 - z^2 + 1 = (z^2+1)^2 - 3z^2 = \cdots$.

Comment: You can factor $z^6+1$ the same way you factor $z^3+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fraction is zero if and only if its numerator is zero, and well-defined if and only if its denumerator is non-zero.
Therefore
$$
  \frac{z^{12} - 1}{(z^4 - 1)(z^3 - 1)} = 0
  \iff
  z^{12} = 1, z^4 \neq 1, z^3 \neq 1.
$$
The solutions of the first condition are given by the $12$-th root of unity, namely
$$
  z = e^{k 2 \pi i / 12}
  \qquad
  k = 0, 1, \dotsc, 11.
$$
We have to exlude the fourth roots of unity and third roots of unity for the other two conditions.
These are
$$
  z
  = e^{k 2 \pi i / 4}
  = e^{(3k) 2 \pi i /12}
  \quad\text{for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$}
$$
and
$$
  z
  = e^{k 2 \pi i / 3}
  = e^{(4k) 2 \pi i / 12}
  \quad\text{for $k = 0, 1, 2$}.
$$
Thus all we are left with is
$$
  z
  = e^{k 2 \pi i / 12}
  \qquad
  k \in \{1,2,5,7,10,11\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Only $$z^{12}-1$$ must equal 0.

Also, find the roots of $$z^{4}-1$$ and $$z^{3}-1$$ and remove them from your final solution, since the denominator ≠ 0